# Delete a node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a test code for BST. The BST is created, but the node deletion is not working properly. Any help to suggest if the below delete code is correct or any modification in delete method would be very helpful.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
  public BinarySearchTree() {
    super();
  }

  private class BinarySearchTreeNode{
    private int data;
    private BinarySearchTreeNode left;
    private BinarySearchTreeNode right;

    public BinarySearchTreeNode(){
    }

    public BinarySearchTreeNode(int data){
      this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
      return data;
    }

    public void setLeft(BinarySearchTree.BinarySearchTreeNode left) {
      this.left = left;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree.BinarySearchTreeNode getLeft() {
      return left;
    }

    public void setRight(BinarySearchTree.BinarySearchTreeNode right) {
      this.right = right;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree.BinarySearchTreeNode getRight() {
      return right;
    }
  }

  public BinarySearchTreeNode insertRec(BinarySearchTreeNode root,int data){
    if(root == null){
      root = new BinarySearchTreeNode(); 
      root.setData(data);
      root.setLeft(null);
      root.setRight(null);
    }else{
        if(data < root.getData())
          root.setLeft(insertRec(root.getLeft(), data));
        else if(data > root.getData())
          root.setRight(insertRec(root.getRight(), data));
    }

    return root;
  }

  public void insertNonRec(BinarySearchTreeNode root,int data){
    if(root == null){
      root = new BinarySearchTreeNode(data); 
      root.setLeft(null);
      root.setRight(null);
    }else{
      if(data < root.getData()){
        if(root.getLeft() != null){
          insertNonRec(root.getLeft(),data);
        }else{
          root.setLeft(new BinarySearchTreeNode(data));
        }
      }else if(data > root.getData()){
        if(root.getRight() != null){
          insertNonRec(root.getRight(), data);
        }else{
          root.setRight(new BinarySearchTreeNode(data));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void delete(BinarySearchTreeNode root,int data){
    BinarySearchTreeNode temp;
    if(root == null){
      System.out.println("No elemets in BST.");
    }else if(data < root.getData()){
      delete(root.getLeft(),data);
    }else if(data > root.getData()){
      delete(root.getRight(),data);
    }else{
      if((root.getLeft() != null) && (root.getRight() != null)){
        // Replace with largest in left subtree 
        temp = findMax(root.getLeft());
        root.setData(temp.getData());
        delete(root.getLeft(),temp.getData());
      }else if(root.getLeft() != null || root.getRight() != null){
        // One child
        if(root.getLeft() == null){
          //root = root.getRight();
          root.setData(root.getRight().getData());
          root.setRight(null);
        }else if(root.getRight() == null){
          //root = root.getLeft();
          root.setData(root.getLeft().getData());
          root.setLeft(null);
        }
      }else{
        root = null;
      }
    }
  }

  public BinarySearchTreeNode findMax(BinarySearchTreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
      return null;

    while(root.getRight() != null)
      root = root.getLeft();

    return root;
  }

  public BinarySearchTreeNode findMin(BinarySearchTreeNode root){
    if(root == null)
      return null;

    while(root.getLeft() != null)
      root = root.getLeft();

    return root;
  }

  public void inOrderRec(BinarySearchTreeNode root){
    if(root != null){
      inOrderRec(root.getLeft());
      System.out.print(root.getData() + " ");
      inOrderRec(root.getRight());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
    BinarySearchTreeNode root = tree.insertRec(null, 10);

    tree.insertNonRec(root, 5);
    tree.insertNonRec(root, 20);
    tree.insertNonRec(root, 4);
    tree.insertNonRec(root, 8);
    tree.insertNonRec(root, 12);
    tree.insertNonRec(root, 30);
    tree.insertNonRec(root, 11);
    tree.insertNonRec(root, 13);

    System.out.println("InOrder Traversal :");
    tree.inOrderRec(root);

    tree.delete(root, 20);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("InOrder Traversal :");
    tree.inOrderRec(root);
  }
}
```

Output :

```
InOrder Traversal :
4 5 8 10 11 12 13 20 30 

InOrder Traversal :
4 5 8 10 11 12 13 11 30
```

Answer (score 1):

`root = null;` doesn't do what you think it does. It changes the value of the local variable only. It does not change the tree. Brief metaphor:

> Think of a classroom of students. The students are the nodes in the tree. They point at each other, which defines parenthood in the tree. Now if another student (say John, i.e. the parameter of the function) were to come along and point at one of the students in the 'tree' (say Sarah), saying `root = null;` would be equivalent to John now pointing nowhere, it would not change Sarah nor what any other students is pointing at.

Sure there are some holes in my metaphor, but I hope you get the basic idea.

You instead need to do something like `node.setLeft(null);` or `node.setRight(null);` to actually change the tree.

This will require quite a few changes, which I'll leave to you to figure out ([this](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~esb/2011fall.ics211/BinarySearchTree.java.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13376070/1711796) may be of some help), but note that for this you'll obviously have to check the left and right children instead of (just) the root.

I also suggest you take a look at [Red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) (or similar) as they provide more efficient means of deleting nodes and also keeps the tree balanced.